# Google app engine direct file upload adds characters to end of file

Tags: php, google-app-engine

I am implementing a file upload in my google app engine php application. When i am uploading a word file with the following code:

```
$bucket = "default";
// Process all files.
$filenames = [];
foreach ($_FILES as $file) {

    $fileName = md5(uniqid());

    $fileName = "gs://".$bucket."/".$fileName;
    stream_context_set_default(['gs' => [
        'Content-Type' => $file['type'],
        'acl' => 'public-read',
        'metadata' => [
            'filename' => $file['name']
        ]
    ]]);
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploaded_files']['tmp_name'], $fileName);

    $filenames[] = $fileName;
}

$file = $filenames[0];
$fileUrl = CloudStorageTools::getPublicUrl($file, true);
```

When i download the file using $fileUrl word says that the file is corrupted. When i run hexdump and vimdiff i get differences in the last part of the file. The file from google app engine has the following extra bytes:

```
0d 0a
```

at the end of the file. Is there anyway to get rid of this other than loading the file content and trim it?
Thank you.

Comment: Sounds like a bug to me. Please file an issue at https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/list?q=Language=PHP